# how to use the 'gazebo::physics::JointFeedback Class' in the model plugin or sensor plugin?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

if I add a model plugin or a sensor plugin, I want to use the gazebo::physics::JointFeedback Class to obtain the force and torque of the link,
or use the gazebo::physics::Joint Class to obtain the force and torque and 'SetForce' to a joint?
what .h file need to include?
and how can I use the class's member function?
thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1513/how-to-use-the-%27gazebo::physics::jointfeedback-class%27-in-the-model-plugin-or-sensor-plugin?/) by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think the minimum includes you'll need are:

```
#include <gazebo/physics/Joint.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/JointWrench.hh>
```

and use the function this way:

```
physics::JointPtr joint = this->model->GetJoint("my_joint_name");
physics::JointWrench wrench = joint->GetForceTorque(0);
```

It's not a good example as it's convoluted, but the [AtlasPlugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/ed05dbae3f24/ros/atlas_msgs/AtlasPlugin.cpp?at=AtlasSimBehaviorLibrary_1.0.3) makes use of the `GetForceTorque` calls to get forces and torques at wrist and ankle.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0